# JSLint Beta error

Tags: javascript, arguments, jslint, console.log, beta

For the following JS function:

```
function cL() {

  'use strict';

  return console.log.apply(console, arguments);

}
```

I get the following JSLint Beta error:

```
Unexpected 'arguments'.
  return console.log.apply(console, arguments);
```

In the older version of JSLint, I never got this error.
Why is the new JSLint Beta not liking this, and what can I do to get rid of / suppress this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to take a little while for me to dig up the changes that catch this now in the new Beta version of JSLint. After keeping things [the same since last July](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/commits/master/jslint.js) Crockford just [changed jslint.js like mad about a week ago](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/commit/557afd32bcaa35480d31a86f02d3a8c06a4e5b5c#diff-01d3d81a6eb6d82af3c377b55dc4fa28), when the beta got pushed out. Guess we know why he was silent for so long.

But here's the quick version while I'm digging up the exact spot in the code: JSLint doesn't want you depending on `arguments` at all. It makes code (in JSLint's opinion) harder to follow.

Say we changed your code to this:

```
/*jslint white:true, devel:true */
function cL() {
  'use strict';
  console.log(arguments[0]);
  return console.log.apply(console, arguments);
}
```

Even on [the old JSLint](http://old.jslint.com), you'd get:

```
Use a named parameter.
  console.log(arguments[0]);
```

JSLint wants that code changed to used named parameters, at a minimum...

```
/*jslint white:true, devel:true */
function cL(p) {
  'use strict';
  console.log(p[0]);
  return console.log.apply(console, p);
}
```

That also works on the beta. Note that I've (natch) also changed `arguments` in your original call to `p`.<sup>* See what this means in the note, below</sup> JSLint does miss stuff, and Crockford rolls in those misses as they're brought to his attention.

I don't believe there's a directive to ignore this issue, but the fix is fairly painless.

Just fwiw, as it makes JSLint's mentality easier for me to understand, anyhow, keep in mind that [JSLint's basic motivation is](https://plus.google.com/+DouglasCrockfordEsq/posts/gocrKmZXYQ4)...

> When you intentionally write things that look like errors, it makes it
>   much harder to find the real errors.
>
> To find the needle, make your program look less like a haystack.

Not having any declared arguments and then referring to them through `arguments` is a little haystack-y, at least from JSLint's point of view. And that makes some sense. `function fn()` at least implies that there's no important parameter being used in the function; you only need to be concerned with closure context. `function fn(p)`, even though the parameter name stinks, is more useful. I know *something's* getting passed in, and will be on the lookout for the needle. (Insert Arya Stark reference.)

---

**Note:** See comments below, which I didn't explain at all the first time. `arguments` is the *entire* array of arguments passed into a function, which means *replacing `arguments` with `p` in my initial function rewrite will drop anything after the first argument*.

I was assuming the OP could pack everything into an array instead of sending as separate arguments, but that wasn't an obvious assumption to make, and I didn't make my assumption that that was the right route clear.

Here's what I mean:

1. Using `cL(arg1, arg2, arg3);` with my version of `cL(p)` would only have `arg1` in `p`.
2. `var a = [arg1, arg2, arg3];cL(a);` would give what the OP wants, but takes defining an array first.
3. `cL([arg1, arg2, arg3]);` is same thing as the previous option, but more concise.

Here's a demo:

```
/*jslint white:true, devel:true */
function cL(p) {
  'use strict';
  if ("string" === typeof p)    {
    p = [p];
  }
  console.log("first arg: " + p[0]);
  return console.log.apply(console, p);
}

var arg1 = "a",
    arg2 = "b",
    arg3 = "c";

cL(arg1, arg2, arg3);   // only arg1 is passed. 'a' is all that's output

var a = [arg1, arg2, arg3];
cL(a);                  // all three argX vars are passed in an array. 'abc'

cL([arg1, arg2, arg3]); // ditto. 'abc'
```

And here's the output (if you're not on IE9- without dev tools open):

```
first arg: a
a
first arg: a
a b c
first arg: a
a b c
```

Comment: Using a parameter like `p` does eliminate the error, but it also breaks my `cL` function whenever I pass more than one argument to it. As such, this doesn't seem like a valid workaround. Your explanation of everything is great though.

Comment: How many different signatures does `cL` have? Or is it literally what you have in your question, a reroute for writing all the args to the console? Depending on what you're doing and how much freedom you have with the code, you could change your calls into `cL([p1, p2, p3])` etc.. If you want to describe the use case in more detail, maybe we could figure out something clever.

Comment: `cL` should simply function as a short alias for `console.log`. That's it. As such, if `console.log` can easily output as many arguments as I please, so should `cL`. The fact is, my `cL` function works fine as is and the old JSLint was cool with it. If the only issue is that the new JSLint Beta doesn't like it, I'm cool with that. I'm not going to write a bunch of parameters in the `cL` declaration to handle a bunch of stuff when `arguments` works fine. I wish there was a workaround for the new JSLint Beta, but maybe not...

Comment: Sorry, I'm caught up. [Allardice's page](http://jslinterrors.com/use-a-named-parameter) goes through some pains to say your old usage is fine (not that Crockford cares): `Note, however, that there are valid use cases for the arguments object. JSLint will only warn when you attempt to access a property of it by numeric index.` Interesting. Might be worth chasing down what's changed in the beta and seeing if Crockford meant to make this change. He is [taking comments](https://plus.google.com/communities/104441363299760713736), but he might say, "Don't alias `console.log`" and be done with it. ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for following that up, ruffin, and looking thoroughly into it. I'm satisfied with your response, even though it's not the answer I wanted, but it totally makes sense, so I will mark your answer as correct.